# Windows Surface app installation

Tags: windows, cordova, powershell, pixelsense

I've following instructions to install this custom cordova app that I downloaded.

1. After you build the app, download the .zip file and extract it. To
   test the app, you use the Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 script.
2. Unzip the file you downloaded from the Apps section of the Portal.
3. Right click the Add-AppDevPackage.ps1 file and select Run with PowerShell. Follow the prompts to obtain a developer license and install the certificate.

The problem is, when i tap and hold on the ps1 file and from context menu I don't see Run with PowerShell option?

Comment: Open a Powershell console, change to the directory where you unzipped the files, run the ps1 script file and follow the prompts to obtain a developer license and install the certificate

Comment: i came across this error. ...ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled, how to enable?

Comment: Read the complete error message and the help mentioned there and follow the instructions.

Comment: It has to do with the Execution Policy on your machine. Google "Powershell Setting Execution Policy"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-5.1

i executed following commands.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```